# Evaluation of derivative: if $p(x)=b_0 + (x-z)q(x)$, then $p'(z)=q(z)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I just wanted to confirm that I did this correctly, because this answer seemed too easy to obtain:

> $p(x)=b_0 + (x-z)(q(x)).$
>
> Show that $p'(z)=q(z).$

My answer:

$$\begin{align*} p'(x) &= (x-z)q'(x)+q(x)\\
p'(z) &= (z-z)q'(z)+q(z) \\
p'(z) &= 0\cdot q'(z)+q(z) \\
p'(z) &= q(z).
\end{align*}$$

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: That is correct, although some additional formatting would make this a much easier read.

Comment: I've also changed the tags, since this question really has nothing to do with Numerical Analysis at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is correct; simply apply the product rule and evaluate at $x=z$.